# Cannot run rxtx on Mac OS

Tags: java, rxtx

I'm trying to use the rxtx JAR file for Java on a Mac (OSX 10.8).  I've installed `RXTXcomm.jar`, the `librxtxSerial.jnilib` and accompanying `.so` files in `/Library/Java/Extensions`.  I'm trying to execute the sample code at:  http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Java

But I am apparently missing something as I get a bunch of `cannot find symbol` error messages.

Here are a couple:

```
SerialTest.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CommPortIdentifier
location: package gnu.io
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
             ^
SerialTest.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SerialPort
location: package gnu.io
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
```

Is there something more basic I am missing within the installed Java on my machine?  I've installed Xcode 4.5 just now, so I would think everything is there to run this simple code.

Folks have asked that I place the libraries in the same directory.  Enclosed is an `ls` and the `javac` command I am running:

```
$javac -classpath RXTXcomm.jar:. SerialTest.java 

SerialTest.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CommPortIdentifier
location: package gnu.io
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
             ^
SerialTest.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SerialPort
location: package gnu.io
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
             ^
SerialTest.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SerialPortEvent
location: package gnu.io
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
             ^
SerialTest.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SerialPortEventListener
location: package gnu.io
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
             ^
SerialTest.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol: class SerialPortEventListener
public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
                                   ^
SerialTest.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SerialPort
location: class SerialTest
    SerialPort serialPort;
    ^
SerialTest.java:83: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SerialPortEvent
location: class SerialTest
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
                                         ^
SerialTest.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CommPortIdentifier
location: class SerialTest
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        ^
SerialTest.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommPortIdentifier
location: class SerialTest
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
                               ^
SerialTest.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CommPortIdentifier
location: class SerialTest
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            ^
SerialTest.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CommPortIdentifier
location: class SerialTest
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
                                             ^
SerialTest.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SerialPort
location: class SerialTest
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                          ^
SerialTest.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable SerialPort
location: class SerialTest
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    ^
SerialTest.java:54: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable SerialPort
location: class SerialTest
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    ^
SerialTest.java:55: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable SerialPort
location: class SerialTest
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                    ^
SerialTest.java:84: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable SerialPortEvent
location: class SerialTest
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
                                     ^
16 errors
MacBook-Pro:src user$ ls
RXTXcomm.jar        comm.jar        librxtxSerial.jnilib
SerialTest.java     librxtxParallel.so  librxtxSerial.so
MacBook-Pro:src user$
```

Is it that I am missing another JAR to make this work?  I do not see these classes in the `RXTXcomm.jar`.

Comment: Sounds like a classpath problem. How are you running your code?

Comment: Both through eclipse by simply running 'compile' or on the command prompt with a simple 'javac SerialTest.java'.  I believe that is all I need to do if the jar is in /Library/Java/Extensions, correct?  I tried a -cp "/Library/Java/Extensions" as well and I still got the same result.

Comment: Sounds like a classpath problem. How are you running your code?

Please try this:

Copy all files, both the shared libraries, the jar file and the sample class, to the same directory, then cd to this directory. Then, from your shell, do a

javac -classpath RXTXcomm.jar:. SerialTest.java 
Then, do a

java -Djava.library.path=. -cp RXTXcomm.jar:. SerialTest

Comment: With all files in the same directory the above still will not work :(

Answer (score 5):

The RXTX library consists of two parts: First that Java/Jar part and second a native library.

The errors you get occur if the Java executable can not find the native `rxtx` library. 
Therefore, you should check where this native library is located. 
The JNI library should have the file extension `.jnilib` or `.dylib`.
Then you have two possibilities:

- **First possibility** is to copy the native library into the directory you are starting Java from (when using Eclipse this is the project directory).
- **Second possibility** is to start Java and specify the library path where the native library is located:

```
java -Djava.library.path=".:/Users/bill/rxtx/jni" MyClass
```

Comment: I did the first possibility but I still have the same issue/error.  How does one 'start java' when just trying to compile in Eclipse?

Comment: @WildBill Put -Djava... in the VM arguments of your Eclipse project run configuration

Comment: Am I missing something else?  Java is complaining about SerialPort not being found.  I do not see that in the RXTXcomm.jar file.

Comment: Also, when I do the -Djava.... options I get a NoClassDefFoundError on SerialTest.... How is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

If after those hints above it still does not work, potentially you have 32-bit RXTX library. On Macs that can run 32-bit apps you can force a client Java VM to work in 32-bit mode (as opposed to what some Java experts say). I managed this way to get rid of the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` by simply invoking java with `-d32` option (mind the lower case as it isn't a Java system property).

My old program to communicate with an old RS-232 based programmer for Atmel processors started just nicely and works fine in 64-bit environment. However, bear in mind that with newer Macs and a 64-bit exclusive environment, that option may not be available - this is the main reason I still keep "dual" Mac OS X Snow Leopard on Core 2 Duo (updgraded from Core Duo with Dell notebook transplant processor) Mac Mini.

Comment: You should consider formatting your text to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project properties pannel, go to libraries, select the button option Compile and click Add Jar/Folder, add the RXTXComm.jar to the list. That work for me.
The compiler see the library because you put in the right place, then and as Netbeans says in the project properties pannel "Compile-time libraries are propagates to all library categories" we expect at run-time the same visibility but don't happen.